# WP_insert_post automation does not work correct

Tags: php, python, wordpress

So I am trying to automate the video upload via FTP and the insertion in the DB.
I wrote a script which is located at the server and uses the included WP funciton:

```
<?php 
$title = $_GET["title"];
$pw = $_GET["key"];
$key = hash('sha256',$pw);
$hash = "hashfromkey";
if ($hash == $key){
$videowebm = $title . ".webm";
$videomp4 = $title . ".mp4";
$image    = $title . ".jpg";

$content = "<video id=\"my-video\" class=\"video-js vjs-big-play-centered\" controls preload=\"auto\" poster='$image' data-setup=\"{}\">
<source src=\"$videomp4\" type='video/mp4'>
<source src=\"$videowebm\" type='video/webm'>
<p class=\"vjs-no-js\"> activate js</p></video> ";

include( "wp-config.php" );

// Gather post data.
$my_post = array(
    'post_title'    => $title,
    'post_content'  => $content,
    'post_author'   => 3
);

// Insert the post into the database.
$ID = wp_insert_post( $my_post, true );
}
?>
```

If I open the URL in my browser `(urltofile?title=jeff&key=key)`, everything works fine.
When using the python script

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
from os import listdir;
adress = 'url';
user = 'ftpuser';
PW = 'ftppw';
url = 'urltofile?title=';
url_short = 'Urltofile';
key = '&key=key';
dir = input("Choose Folder");
for file in dir:
    if file.endswith(".txt"):
        print(file)
        urlges = url + file + key;
        #data = urllib.parse.urlencode(data);
        #data = data.encode('utf-8');
        html_quelltext = urllib.request.urlopen(urlges).read();
```

I get

```
   <video id="my-video" class="video-js vjs-big-play-centered" controls preload="auto" poster='Testscribbles.txt.jpg'>

<p class="vjs-no-js"> activate js</p></video>
```

So I am missing the two lines where I specify my sources. I don't understand why it happens only when using the script (I had the same script in Perl, got the same result).
I tried it with a get statement from urllib but I could not get it to work (probably a different problem).

Does anybody have an idea what the solution might be?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
remove_all_filters("content_save_pre");
```

Is the solution to my problem. Wordpress tries to sanitize the code to prevent harmful codes.

Answer (score 0):

By default Wordpress [post status](https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Status)' are "Draft" which is somewhat unpublished, depending on your theme settings.

Based on your current requirements, perhaps "publish" is what you need:

```
// Gather post data.
$my_post = array(
    'post_title'    => $title,
    'post_content'  => $content,
    'post_author'   => 3,
    'post_status'   => 'publish'
);

// Insert the post into the database.
$ID = wp_insert_post( $my_post, true );
```

Comment: I would like to create a draft post. I will try it tomorrow, but I don't think this will solve my problem.